# How to prevent the scroll of table when click to header on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have some code to draw a table with fixed header. But there is something wrong with the scroll on Chrome.

First: pull the scroll to bottom.

Second: click to anywhere on the header of the table and the scroll will be run to the top.

I have tried with css `-webkit-user-select: none;` but it only works on IE.

I don't want to change the html code like `<div>` or `<table>`.

How to prevent the scroll when I click on header?

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollerBox">
    <div id="weeklyShifts">
        <table class="scrollContent">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>a01</th>
                    <th>a02</th>
                    <th>a03</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="scheduleShifts">
        <table class="scrollContent">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                    <td>b01</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                    <td>b02</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollerBox {
    width:  360px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#weeklyShifts {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
}
#weeklyShifts table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#weeklyShifts tr:first-child {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333333;
}
#scheduleShifts table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#scheduleShifts tr {
    border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
}
table.scrollContent tr {
    border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    border-left: none;
}
#weeklyShifts   table th:nth-child(1),
#scheduleShifts table th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
    border-right: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
}
#weeklyShifts   table th:nth-child(2),
#scheduleShifts table td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
#weeklyShifts   table th:nth-child(3),
#scheduleShifts table td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
#weeklyShifts table thead th {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 0.88em;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.4em;
    border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#weeklyShifts table thead th span {
    display: block;
}
#weeklyShifts table thead th span.term {
    float: left;
}
#scheduleShifts table tbody th {
    height: 54px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.28em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.8em 0.4em;
}
#scheduleShifts table td {
    font-size: 0.88em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0.32em;
    border: solid 1px #cfcfcf;
}
#scheduleShifts table td span {
    display: block;
}
#scheduleShifts table td span.sub {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#weeklyShifts table th:first-child span + span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
#scheduleShifts tbody th:first-child {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
table.scrollContent thead {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 32;
}
```

[The code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/thanhtp1/myw5kn8y/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is the right behaviour in Chrome.

For example, the same issue happens with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/) code. In Firefox or IE the behaviour is different.

Anyway, you could handle the `mousedown` event and prevent it so the event won't be notified to the parent handlers.

If you can use jQuery, this is the code to achieve this:

```
$("div#weeklyShifts").mousedown(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("here!"); // just to test
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2w9ctpjt/) you have the idea already implemented.

You can also try to set the `pointer-events` property to `none` in your CSS `#weeklyShifts` id:

```
#weeklyShifts {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #cfcfcf; 
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

See the complete code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s739ox77/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edit. 
The problem is fixed with code:
$("div#weeklyShifts").mousedown(function(e){
    return false;
});

Comment: I have try very very the css to fix it but fails. Do you know any css to resolve it?

Comment: You're welcome :) Answer updated! Try with `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: Thanks to you :) Happy coding!